# Association not finding created objects in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, shoulda, factory-bot

I have following models in my app:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :players
   has_many :villages, :through => :players
end

class Village < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :game
   has_many :villages

   before_create :build_starting_village

   protected

   def build_starting_village
     villages.build(some_attributes)
   end
end
```

I am testing some part of Game functionality with Shoulda/FactoryGirl, this is the test:

```
  setup do
    @villages = []
    5.times do |i|
      p = Factory(:player, :game => @game)
      v = p.villages.first
      assert v
      @villages << v
    end
    assert_equal @villages.size, @game.villages.size
  end
```

The problem is that the last assert fails. I have tried many ugly things like:

```
    @game.villages(true)
    @game.players(true)
    @game = Game.find(@game.id)
```

But I can't see to get to the root of the problem. I have tried disabling transactional fixtures (I do not use fixtures, but I think this also affect Factory girl) and it helped in other tests but here it has no effect.

The assert in the setup block fails in about 1 of 4 runs. I am trying to suspect MySQL... When I debug it from RubyMine everything passes with the reloading statements, but not from command-line.

Comment: I have been able to fix the issue by changing what seems to me unrelated code. I will definitely come back to this and find out why.

Answer (score 1):

try asserting something other than truthiness because it could be anything, eg `assert_instance_of Village`

also what happens in the following case? Forgive me for any slight syntax mistakes, haven't used test::unit/shoulda in a while, but in your code, not sure where `@game` comes from

```
def test_player_has_village_on_new
  p = Factory(:player, :game => Factory(:game))
  assert_equal 1, p.villages.size
end
```

Comment: I alrady have this test and it passes

Comment: output both villages and game with an inspect statement, eg `puts @villages.inspect` so you can see them when the test fails.